# Synonymize [esri-javascript-api] to [arcgis-js-api]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

It appears the [Esri](https://www.esri.com/en-us/home) is the company and [all their products](https://www.esri.com/en-us/arcgis/products/index) fall under the [ArcGIS product suite](http://www.arcgis.com/index.html); I couldn't find an Esri product that was separate from ArcGIS. So I'm proposing that [esri-javascript-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esri-javascript-api) be synonymized to [arcgis-js-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-js-api) and its 30 questions retagged to [arcgis-js-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arcgis-js-api) (518 questions).

I've never used Esri products or ArcGIS so there could be a purpose for having separate tags, but if so then it would make sense to distinguish them in some way (right now [esri-javascript-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esri-javascript-api) doesn't even have a description). It probably makes sense to also synonymize [esri](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/esri) to [arcgis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arcgis), but I'll leave that request to someone else since it's a much bigger scope...